# How to enable dbus-X11 in the yocto

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I'm using poky and meta-openembedded(git://git.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded(branch: master)) in yocto

I want to build metacity and cyrus-sasl(2.1.26) for my SDK platform
I run the following command

I add BBCLASSEXTEND += " nativesdk" to metacity's bb
and run bitbake nativesdk-metacity

but I will get error message

> ERROR: Nothing RPROVIDES 'nativesdk-dbus-x11' (but virtual:nativesdk:poky/meta/rec on or otherwise requires it)
>
> ERROR: Nothing RPROVIDES 'nativesdk-dbus-x11' (but virtual:nativesdk:poky/meta/recipes-core/dbus/dbus-glib_0.110.bb RDEPENDS on or otherwise requires it) ERROR: Required build target 'nativesdk-metacity' has no buildable providers. Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['nativesdk-metacity', 'nativesdk-libcanberra', 'nativesdk-pulseaudio', 'nativesdk-gconf', 'nativesdk-dbus-glib', 'nativesdk-dbus-x11']
>
> ERROR: Nothing PROVIDES 'dbus-x11'. Close matches:
>     dbus RPROVIDES dbus-x11

I cannot find dbus-x11's bb in my all meta
and I cannot see dbus-x11 then run bitbake -s

How can I enable dbus-x11 ??

and...

I also add BBCLASSEXTEND += " nativesdk" to cyrus-sasl_2.1.26.bb
and bitbake nativesdk-cyrus-sasl

get error message

> | x86_64-pokysdk-linux-gcc  --sysroot=/poky/build-fw/tmp/work/x86_64-nativesdk-pokysdk-linux/nativesdk-cyrus-sasl/2.1.26-r0/recipe-sysroot  -O2 -pipe  -Wl,-O1 -o saslauthd mechanisms.o auth_dce.o auth_getpwent.o auth_krb5.o auth_krb4.o auth_pam.o auth_rimap.o auth_httpform.o auth_shadow.o auth_sia.o auth_sasldb.o lak.o auth_ldap.o cache.o cfile.o krbtf.o utils.o ipc_unix.o ipc_doors.o saslauthd-main.o md5.o  -lresolv
>
> ```
> | auth_getpwent.o: In function `auth_getpwent':
> | auth_getpwent.c:(.text+0x42): undefined reference to `crypt'
> | auth_shadow.o: In function `auth_shadow':
> | auth_shadow.c:(.text+0x109): undefined reference to `crypt'
> | collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> | Makefile:456: recipe for target 'saslauthd' failed
> ```

How can I add -lcrypt to cyrus-sasl_2.1.26.bb bb??

thanks a lot
John

Comment: Poky removed the dependency with x11 for dbus nativesdk long back, check here : https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/commit/?id=0f8d6f8143ebad040550b0c97671eb3e1a5c4b9b. Also `dbus-x11` is the old name `dbus` package. This package name exists in https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/recipes-core/dbus/dbus_1.12.10.bb#n46 only for backward compatibility reason. This is not available for nativesdk

Comment: crypt support is removed from glibc, see here https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/recipes-core/glibc/glibc/0031-nativesdk-deprecate-libcrypt.patch?h=sumo and moved to new package libxcrypt here https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/recipes-core/libxcrypt?h=sumo, you may need to use libxcrypt.

Comment: Thank a lot. I can build ipk package now.